# Is there a way to check size of the packet sent/received in Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Just as in title. I am trying to check the size of the packets sent and received by Node.js server using Socket.io.

Comment: One more thing the actual packet depends on the transport protocol agreed upon by the client and server. It can be any of these [websocket , jsonpolling ,flashsocket , xhrpolling].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you understand under 'packets'.
If it is just the payload you are after, then ProblemFactory has the correct answer.
Trying to get the size of the socket.io packages themselves, is not possible through the socket.io API.

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.stringify(response).length` should do the trick.

Comment: This returns the string size, but 1 string length is not 1 byte. `String.fromCharCode(2000).length` is not 1 byte but actually returns 1.